# Google Checkout Subscription payment not happen (daily, monthly or yearly)

Tags: subscription, google-checkout, android-pay

I integrated PayPal and Google checkout subscription payment to a site. PayPal is almost fine and i received subscription payment. However i have a problem with Google checkout.

Example: -

I created a subscription payment with $1 (daily subscription)

I received "New Order Notification" and "Authorization Amount Notification" but not "Charge Amount Notification"

When i create subscription payment profile i set start date as previous date (example today 28/01/2013 then start date set to 27/01/2013). Because then  i will received subscription payment on 28/01/2013 again.

However still I'm not received any subscription payment from google checkout and profile doesn't showing any subscription payment happen

*note i use subscription type as merchant

What is the problem not to get subscription payments daily? is it a problem of starting date?

Comment: Hey user1903988, I've been looking for a Google Subscription script.. something simple. If you're interested in a small project, and since you already have the work done.. please contact me asap ! Thanks!!

Comment: yes i completed google suscription project. what kind of help u need?

Comment: Well, all kinds LOL!! I am trying to setup a simple form to start new subscriptions.. but, I'm a front-end developer, not a back end coder!! Interested in a small project??!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error....

I used merchant handled subscription instead of google handled subscription

when i used google handled subscription it worked..